# Check card PIN using directly scdaemon Assuan protocol

Tags: smartcard, gnupg

I am learning the internals of GnuPG. I want to perform a simple card PIN verification with scdaemon. I do the following (`>` are client inputs, `<` are server responses):

```
$ /lib/gnupg/scdaemon --server
> CHECKPIN <card_id>
< INQUIRE NEEDPIN ...
> D <something>
> END
```

My problem is that I do not know what goes in the `<something>` place.

Some other commands use an s-expression formatted answer, but I can not find any documentation related to `CHECKPIN`.

Can someone provide documentation references?

Answer (score 0):

scdaemon Assuan protocol `INQUIRE NEEDPIN` expects a zero-padded fixed size response of 88 bytes. Example:

```
$ /lib/gnupg/scdaemon --server
> CHECKPIN <card_id>
< INQUIRE NEEDPIN ...
> D 123456<82 zero bytes>
> END
```